# Show/Hide Content

Tags: javascript, events, show-hide, sections

I need to create a <strike>*script in which will hide all content but one section in which is selected for my JavaScript class.*</strike> function in which listens for a click event to a specific HTML section. Once this event has been triggered I need to show the section in which was clicked while having the other sections hidden. I think I have coded the `EventListener`'s and the `hide function` properly! However, I think where I'm running into these issues is with my function. Sadly, this has to be done all in JavaScript (with HTML and some CSS). We need to have a navigation bar and have querySelectors along with event.targets.

Here's what I have so far:

Set object references

```
link1 = document.getElementById("program");
link2 = document.getElementById("history");
link3 = document.getElementById("efficiency");
link4 = document.getElementById("brains");
```

Add event listener

```
addEventListener("click", clicked);
link1.addEventListener("click", clicked);
link2.addEventListener("click", clicked);
link3.addEventListener("click", clicked);
link4.addEventListener("click", clicked);
```

Shows Content

```
function clicked(event){

    for (var i = 0; i<sections.length; i++){
        sections[i].className = "hidden"; //Looks at all the sections then changes/adds all the class names to "hidden"
    }

    event.target.href;
    event.target.className = "";

    //event.target.hash.className = "show";

    console.log(event.target.hash); //Logs tha function works and which link has been clicked
}
```

I was wondering if I could get some help?!

My full code is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhpzerhc/)!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have narrowed down my question!

Comment: You're unlikely to get any help with the question as it is @KD_13 - try narrowing it down to a single distinct issue, and asking that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JamesMonger! I have just done so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need some way to link the titles to their sections. I have done this by adding [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to the navbar links:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#program" data-section="program">Programming</a>
    <a href="#history" data-section="history">History</a>
    <a href="#efficiency" data-section="efficiency">Efficiency</a>
    <a href="#brains" data-section="brains">Brains</a>
</nav>
```

As you can see, the `data-section` attribute is the exact ID of the section we want to open.

Then, we need to be able to get the section for a given `data-section` attribute:

```
function getSection(name) {
    // find the section element with ID matching the name
    return document.querySelector("section#" + name);
}
```

Then, in our `clicked` event, we need to:

1. Get the `data-section` information from the clicked element
2. Get the element for the section
3. Add the class `show` to the section element

We can do this like so:

```
var name = event.target.dataset.section;
var section = getSection(name);
section.className = "show";
```

I've stored my changes on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhpzerhc/2/) so you can see.

Comment: No worries. Welcome to Stack Overflow!